# PHP comparing value taken from sqli query and same value returns false

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting an Int from a table, then comparing it to the (should be) same number passed through the URL. However they seem to be different values.

```
$access = $_GET["access"];//Num passed from url
$access = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $access);

$verifyCode = "select access FROM users WHERE userName = '".$userName."'";
$verifyCodeX = mysqli_query($con, $verifyCode);//Getting number from table
while($codeResult = mysqli_fetch_array($verifyCodeX))
{
     $codeResult = $codeResult['access'];
     echo "$codeResult";
     echo "<br>";
     echo "$access";
     if($access == $codeResult)//comparing
     {
        echo "working fine";
     }
     else
     {
    echo "Numbers not the same";
     }

}
```

When I echo the numbers they are exactly the same, but I still get "Numbers not the same".

Comment: show us the results from: `var_dump($codeResult);var_dump($access);`

Comment: _why_ are you doing this: `$access = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $access);`? If you're not going to use `$access` in a query... don't do that. It alters the content.

Comment: both $access or $codeResult can be strings a lot longer then the number you see..
Var_dump them both to see what length they are. Echo wont be enough help

Answer (score 0):

As Wrikken said, I should have not used a real_escape_string. I forgot I wasn't going to use it in a query, so I left it there. Removing that line fixed it.

Comment: if $access was an int, mysqli_real_escape_string would do noting to it